# No puedo usar bucle for con webdriver

Tags: bucle-for, selenium-webdriver, find

```
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
from selenium import webdriver 
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys 
import time

pagina = "https://www.centraloeste.com.ar/ofertas.html"

driver = webdriver.Edge()  
driver.get(pagina)  

contenido = driver.page_source
time.sleep(5)

sopa = BeautifulSoup(contenido, "lxml") #obtengo todo el codigo html

Caja_total= sopa.find_all("div", class_= "page-wrapper") #obtengo todo lo que esa definido dentro de esa clase

for i in sopa():
    Cada_art = i.find("a", class_= "product-item-link") #aca no me deja usar find
    Cada_precio = i.find("span", class_= "price") #aca no me deja usar find
    print(Cada_art)
    print(Cada_precio)
```

cuando uso este codigo con request me funciona bien, pero para paginas de carga dinamica en los que se  requiera WebDriver, no me deja usar find dentro del bucle for.